# Can we apply animation on Navigation icons?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

My question may have something to do [Drawer animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448807/custom-animation-for-navigation-drawer-open-and-close) , and since it is a library. I don't want it.

I want to know:

**How can I map (findViewById) the icons inside the `NavigationView` - `DrawerLayout` in order to apply animations like - delay to appear** (the icons only).

From: `YouVersion` App

[image: YouVersion]

Someone suggested from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070831/can-i-open-the-drawer-layout-with-animation-programmatically) comment to use `postDelayed` . But it is for the drawer.

Comment: Instead of specifying them as `@menu` items, just replicate them in a layout. And then you're good to go with any animation.

Comment: Do you mean, I will create a separate layout. And from the `NavigationView` - `app:menu=" custom_menu.xml " ` . I will just use `LinearLayout - Vertical` with buttons with style same selectors with the nav?

Comment: You can [addHeaderView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) to your `NavigationView`. The rest is right in your comment.

Comment: Many Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inflating as menu items, just create a layout with same UI, perform [`NavigationView.addHeaderView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)). And thereafter you can perform any animation on those views.